# Four Errors In C++ Code, I Can't Find The Solutions To

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I was looking at some code I'm working on, and there are 3-4 errors that I have tried for about a week to get rid of, and I just can't do it!  I'm kind of new to programming, so if you could answer in stupid form, that would be great!  Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    string password;

    int choice;

    cout << "Command Line Multi-Tool" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "plase enter your password: " << endl;
    cin >> password;
    if (password == "creeper1") {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
        cout << "1. Class Schedule" << endl;
        cout << "2. School Info" << endl;
        cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect, Access Denied" << endl;
        return(0);
    }

    }

    else (password == "admin1"){
        cout << "/*adminLogin=='1'*/" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Menu::Main" << endl;
    }

    return(0);

    }

}
```

And here is the error log.

```
/Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:31:0 /Users/student/Documents/TO BE
FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:31: error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'


/Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36:0 /Users/student/Documents/TO BE
FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'


/Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36:0 /Users/student/Documents/TO BE
FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36: error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

Again thanks so much!

Comment: 1 if, two else and a bracket error. this isnt xcode specific

Comment: There's no proper indentation, but I suppose that the reason of the extra-braces is right this: he doesn't see when a block ends.

Comment: Storing password in plain-text is bad idea. However, if you have C++11 available, you can use `std::hash<std::string>`

Comment: It looks like you deleted an if statement at some point, just remove the else and the block and recompile

Comment: eventually I will store it in an fstream, but for now I am just using those as fillers.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

You have one `if` but 2 `else` brances in your code. Decide which one you want and lose the other one. Looking at the code you probably want

```
 if (password == "creeper1") {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. Class Schedule" << endl;
    cout << "2. School Info" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
 } else if (password == "admin1")
    // Your processing code here
 }  else {
    cout << "Incorrect, Access Denied" << endl;
    return(0);
 }
```

Comment: Also there is an extra `}` after `return` in the end and 1 before `else`.

Comment: Actually, the `main()` ends before reaching the second `else`

Comment: @icepack yes but the compiler will still not like it

Comment: @mathematician1975 of course, I'm just pointing out that the problem is even bigger... People doesn't want to make even the slightest effort to understand before posting a question to SO

Comment: Thank you,  i just tried it and got: /Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:31:0 /Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:31: error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'


/Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36:0 /Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'


/Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36:0 /Users/student/Documents/TO BE FILED/Tuesday/main.cpp:36: error: expected declaration before '}' token

Answer (score 2):

Unbalanced `else`,i.e. without a corresponding `if`.

Perhaps you wanted something like:

```
if (password == "creeper1") {
}
else if (password == "admin1") {
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an else if after an else, that block will never be executed.Also, the right syntax is return 0, not return(0).
You also include extra braces, but if you indent the code in the right way you see when a block ends and starts, so you could rarely make mistakes like adding an extra brace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;

    int choice;



    cout << "Command Line Multi-Tool" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "plase enter your password: " << endl;
    cin >> password;
    if (password == "creeper1")
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
        cout << "1. Class Schedule" << endl;
        cout << "2. School Info" << endl;
        cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }
    else if(password == "admin1")
    {
        cout << "/*adminLogin=='1'*/" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Menu::Main" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Incorrect, Access Denied" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code with all the syntax errors fixed.About semantics I don't know if it works, but now you can compile and execute it, to test the code.

Comment: return(0) looks fine to me, I'd agree it is bad form for just one int... but it makes sense for return(array.count>0 && flag) or something. it works anyways

Answer (score 0):

becasue else cannot comprise judgement
the correct usage is like this:

if(password == "creeper1"){

}
else if(password == "admin1"){

}
else{

}